# How Can i display detail Data by ID on JQUERY AJAX?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

so I have managed to display all the contents of the article from json, then how can I display the contents or details of the article on another page when i clicked the list of article with jquery ajax?

This is My Ajax Show list All Data

```
function showAllData() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/artikel",
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      let artikel = data.artikel;
      $.each(artikel, function (i, data) {
        $("#list-all-artikel").append(
          `<a class="see-detail" href="">
          <div class="row mb-4">
            <div class="col-5">
              <img class="w-100" src="` +
            data.gambar +
            `" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
              <div class="tittle-date">
                <ion-icon name="calendar-outline"></ion-icon>   ` +
            data.created +
            `
              </div>
              <div class="tittle-article mb-1">
                ` +
            data.judul +
            `
              </div>
              <span class="badge badge-pill badge-green">  ` +
            data.kategori +
            `</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>`
        );
      });
    },
  });
}
```

This is my Request that show detail data
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/detail_artikel/11

```
{
    "status": true,
    "artikel": {
        "kategori": "Program",
        "id": 11,
        "id_kategori": "2",
        "tag_program": "2",
        "nm_program": "Zakat Mall",
        "gambar": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/photos/1/article3.png",
        "judul": "Menumbuhkan Semangat Berzakat Umat",
        "preview": null,
        "konten": null,
        "created": "2020-12-11",
        "modified": "2020-12-11"
    }
}
```

And now how i can display detail article by id on another page when i clicked the list article ?
I managed to display it in modal but (on the same page), but how to display the detailed data on a different page ? thanks for your answer guys